# What happen when web service change its method signature which is used by desktop application?

Tags: c#, web-services

For example, web service provide two methods,

```
a(int a,int b)

b(string str)
```

to provide some service and desktop application use this two methods.

Later after few days for any reasons web service change it's methods signature and is it possible desktop application get notify about this change. Can anyone explain what gonna happen in this situation ?

Thanks in Advance friends.

Comment: If the method signature changed,It'll definitely affect to the desktop application.If you didn't handle the errors it might give some errors.
You should change the desktop application also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the changes. If you add new methods then the client application should not be affected. Changes to the existing methods will definitely break the client when it calls those methods. The best way around this is to create a method on the web service that returns the version number of the server. You can then decide on the client what to do when the version changes. Probably the best course of action in that case is to download an update of the client and install that.

You could work around some things by using ServiceDescriptionImporter and dynamically calling the web server methods but I can't see how that would help you as the client would need to be modified to know what to do with the new methods, when to call them, and what information to pass through to them, etc.